# Undefined constant "text" in /home/jokebo/public_html/index.php:23

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP project which is connected to an SQL Database.
The problem is I cant access to the value of the *text* in the following code:

```
 $sher = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sher1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
 $matn = $sher[0][text];
```

what is wrong?
how can I fix it?

access to a table value in arrays

Comment: `SELECT *` is inefficient and you should ideally be listing each column you actually need e.g `SELECT name, id, text FROM...`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and include the stucture of the `sher1` table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a result (more than 0 in result) and there are "text" column. You are missing the doublequote because "text" without doublequote would be recognized as a constant. here is the fix

```html
$sher = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sher1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$matn = $sher[0]["text"];
```